# Why don't the compiler take the namespace name when the inner scope ones don't work?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc, c++11

I thought I understood name lookup very well (after having watched several videos about it and read a lot) but I just hit this case:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace test{

  struct Id
  {};

  void do_something( const Id& ){  std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl; }

  class Test
  {
  public:

    void do_something() { std::cout << "WTF!" << std::endl;  }

    void run()
    {
      Id id;
      do_something( id ); // doesn't compile
    }

  };

}

int main()
{
    test::Test my_test;
  my_test.run();
}
```

The pointed line don't compile (on GCC4.8 and VC11U2) because it tries to use the member function  `test::Test::do_something()` instead of the namespace-scoped `test::do_something( const Id& )` which seem like the only possible candidate.

Apparently the member function name hides the namespace-scoped names which is surprising to me because I remember using almost similar code in other context without this problem spawning (but the conditions might have be very different in the end).

My question is: **are these compilers confirming to the standard?**

(Name lookup is very hard to understand by reading the standard document unfortunately, so I need expert confirmations)

Comment: No, no.  Name lookup is easy.  It's just [a simple little formula.](https://twitter.com/JamesMcNellis/status/336513318686695424)

Comment: `do_something` isn't global; it's in the `test` namespace.

Comment: @chepner Truem let me fix this.

Answer (score 6):

> My question is: **are these compilers confirming to the standard?**

Yes.  Before overload resolution decides which functions are *viable* candidates (which includes checking the number of parameters) the compiler first has to do name lookup, to find all candidates, viable and non-viable.  In your example name lookup stops after finding the member `do_something()` so overload resolution never gets a chance to decide whether the namespace-scope one is viable.

> 3.4.1 [basic.lookup.unqual]/1: "In all the cases listed in 3.4.1, the scopes are searched for a declaration in the order listed in each of the respective categories; name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name."

3.4.1 [basic.lookup.unqual] paragraph 8 lists the contexts searched for the name and even has an example that answers your question exactly.  The scope of `Test` is searched before the enclosing namespace, and as paragraph 1 says **"name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name"**.

Answer (score 4):

The further a language goes out of its way to find a valid interpretation for a construct, the more likely it is that a typo or other such mistake will result in the compiler finding a meaning which is valid but *wrong*.  The compiler is assuming that if `foo` is defined within some scope, and code within that scope uses `foo`, the programmer intends for the code to use the `foo` that is defined within the scope.  If the programmer tries to do something with `foo` that is not permitted by its inner scope definition, odds are very good that one of the following is true:

- The programmer meant to do some other slightly different operation, which would have been valid on the inner foo.  A compiler could not be expected to know what the programmer intends unless the programmer specifies it.
- The programmer meant to do the indicated operation, not realizing that the inner `foo` can't support it, and will thus have to find some other operation or sequence of operations the inner `foo` can support.  Again, a compiler can't be expected to generate good code unless the programmer indicates how to use `foo` properly.
- The programmer meant to do the operation in question on the outer foo, but declined to explicitly say so.  If the compiler wanted to guess that this is what the programmer meant, it could generate code which would behave this way.

Only if the programmer's intention was #3 could a compiler possibly generate code which would behave as intended.  It's far more likely, however, that a programmer really intended #1 or #2.  If the compiler refuses to compile code even when assuming #3 would produce *valid* code, then any of the above mistakes will be found and can thus be corrected.  By contrast, if compiler assumed #3 whenever it could, then if the programmer really intended #1 or #2 problems would not manifest themselves until the code was run and behaved contrary to design.

BTW, if I had my druthers, I would apply this principle to case-sensitivity in .NET languages, forbidding not only the writing of any identifier in a fashion inconsistent with the definition (as is done by C# but not vb.net), but the use of any identifier which differs only in upper/lower-casing from one in an inner scope.  For example:

```
class foo
{
  int x;
  void bar()
  {
    int X=2;
    x=4; // ****
    return X;
  }
}
```

Given the above code, C# would guess that the line with the asterisks was intended to write the field; given similar code, vb.net would assume it was intended to write the local variable.  Personally, I dislike both assumptions; the principle of "say exactly what you mean" would suggest to me that a compiler should require the programmer to either say `this.x=4;` or `X=4;`, neither of which could possibly be read as having the wrong meaning.

Comment: +1, though I don't agree with using `this` everywhere.  That's a bug that hits beginners, not a bug which is likely to cause chaos in real world applications.  Also, the compiler emits a warning.

Comment: @EdS.: The only "extra" time I would require `this` would be in the scenario where a local variable exists with a name which is identical except for upper/lower-casing.  Incidentally, I really dislike the popular C# convention where the private backing field for property `Foo` is called `foo`; I see no advantage to that over `_foo` or `_Foo`.  To my mind, the leading underscore is more visually distinctive than lowercase initial latter, and it is legal in no fewer contexts as field names which differ from property names in case only.

Comment: Ad 3) I think this isn't always possible, e.g. if an argument type of a function is a template parameter.

Comment: @supercat: Oh, then I suppose I misunderstood you and we completely agree :D.  I dislike backing fields using only lowercase as well for the same reason; they conflict with method parameters all over the place.

Comment: @EdS.: Many people who want case sensitivity mainly want to have the compiler squawk if identifiers are written with the wrong case, and many people who want case insensitivity mainly want to have the compiler squawk if have identifiers that differ only by case.  Why not make both groups of people happy, and require that identifiers be cased correctly, but also differ by more than case.  It's too late to impose such a rule retrospectively, but I would think it would have offered the best of both worlds.

Comment: @supercat: Because I honestly never run into problems due to case sensitivity (I prefer case sensitivity) and writing `this` everywhere adds nothing but redundant verbosity.

Comment: @EdS.: The only additional scenario where `this` would be required would be if an inner-scope name nearly (except for case) matched an outer-scope name.  If you don't want to write `this`, choose a meaningfully different inner-scope name.  If code doesn't need to use the outer-scope name, it's fine to just ignore its existence; if an inner-scope name happens to match, there's no problem.  But I think good code should avoid creating inner-scope names that are overly similar to outer-scope names that it also uses.

Comment: Agreed, which is why I also agree on the private field naming scheme you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an issue of lookup at all. The key point is that lookup completes **before** overload resolution kicks in. When the compiler sees `do_something` it performs lookup to figure out what it means, it finds that it is a function, which in turn activates ADL to find other potential overloads. Then lookup completes and overload resolution starts. When overload resolution fails.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will gather up all "candidate names", which will be from the same scope unless ADL is involved, and then try to pick the best match if one is available. Under no circumstances will a failed match cause it to attempt to find additional candidate names from alternate scopes.

This is very similar to how compilers do overload resolution first and THEN check the public/private of the member to see if it's actually accessible.

g++ has a handy `-Wshadow` option to hunt down shadows (I'm not sure it would warn about this one specifically though).

Comment: [basic.lookup.unqual] "name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name." Does it really gather **all** names?

Comment: @Klaim "Let X be the lookup set produced by unqualified lookup (3.4.1) and let Y be the lookup set produced by argument dependent lookup (defined as follows). If X contains - a declaration of a class member, or [...] then Y is empty." basic.lookup.argdep]/3

Comment: @DyP O____o what? I missed that part. So if I understand correctly, ADL  is cleared or "removed" because the call is in a class member? That doni't seem useful at all. What problem does it fix?

Comment: @Klaim: The problem of namespace functions that are a better match stealing your member call?

Comment: @Xeo good point, but why not fix this with an explicit `this->` -- which would be simpler IMO than to find the namespace where the namespace-scope function is defined and use a qualified-id?

Comment: @Xeo DyP is right, because the current rules forbid generic non-member functions to be written in generic code which is member of a class, while specifying the member use instead of the outter function use is a local solution to a local problem. Also in my current case there is no valid member names for the call so it could have considered other names in this specific case.

Comment: "but why not fix this with an explicit this->" Then you'd have to write every member function with `this->`, even when there's no current external function that steals the lookup. Otherwise future changes to external code could change the meaning of your code. @DyP

Comment: @bames53 I'm ok with writing `this->` everywhere, but I see your point. Especially if you allow leaving out `this->` there is no point in requiring it in most cases because of name lookup.

Comment: I'm **not** OK with writing `this->` everywhere.  The rules do **not** _"forbid generic non-member functions to be written in generic code which is member of a class"_, if you mean to include non-member names then put `using test::do_something;` otherwise it should find the "nearest" name (i.e. starting from the current scope and working outwards into enclosing scopes)

Answer (score 1):

> Name lookup is very hard to understand by reading the standard document unfortunately, so I need expert confirmations

I'm not an expert by any means, but here's how I understand the name lookup rules of the Standard.

Two examples:

```
void foo(int);

namespace associated
{
    struct bee {};
    void flower(bee);
}

namespace bar
{
    void foo();
    void flower();

    void test()
    {
        foo(42);                   // (A)
        flower(associated::bee()); // (B)
    }
}

int main()
{
    bar::test();
}
```

(A) does not compile, because of [basic.lookup.unqual]: "name lookup ends as soon as a declaration is found for the name"

(B) does compile, because of ADL; `associated` is an associated namespace.

However, there's [basic.lookup.argdep]/3:

> Let X be the lookup set produced by unqualified lookup (3.4.1) and let Y be the lookup set produced by argument dependent lookup (defined as follows). If X contains
>
> - a declaration of a class member, or
> - a block-scope function declaration that is not a using-declaration, or
> - a declaration that is neither a function or a function template
>
> then Y is empty. Otherwise Y is the set of declarations found in the namespaces associated with the argument types as described below. The set of declarations found by the lookup of the name is the union of X and Y.

The first point applies in your example. Therefore, I think yes, the compilers that reject your example comply with the Standard.

Comment: this is why often you will find "using std::swap;" in implementations of class member swap functions (in addition of bringing swap into scope for fundamental types like `int` ofc). Prevents lookup to the member swap function that would prevent ADL from working.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb Is there any way to make a declaration visible of a function declared in a namespace where the namespace depends on a template type argument?